# Sends a message to a non-existent exchange and catch exception

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I publish message to a non-existent exchange using rabbitmq-java client

Code:

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("55.11.55.131");
    factory.setUsername("e93b7d0d-ba17-42a2-91c6-d488863019fd");
    factory.setPassword("51681201-0313-4b5c-a0d5-006b345e25a9");
    factory.setVirtualHost("9d0cf636-17f5-4828-a21f-d7a4145f1f83");
    factory.setPort(5672);
    try (Connection conn = factory.newConnection(); Channel channel = conn.createChannel();) {
        try {
            channel.basicPublish("exchange_not_exists", "abc", new AMQP.BasicProperties(), "ABC".getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception2");
        // catch exception: Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'exchange_not_exists' in vhost
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Thread.sleep(100000);
```

Why is `Exception2` printed ?

And if I change code to this, no exceptions will be printed:

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("55.11.55.131");
    factory.setUsername("e93b7d0d-ba17-42a2-91c6-d488863019fd");
    factory.setPassword("51681201-0313-4b5c-a0d5-006b345e25a9");
    factory.setVirtualHost("9d0cf636-17f5-4828-a21f-d7a4145f1f83");
    factory.setPort(5672);
    Connection conn = factory.newConnection(); Channel channel = conn.createChannel();
    try {
        channel.basicPublish("exchange_not_exists", "abc", new AMQP.BasicProperties(), "ABC".getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Thread.sleep(100000);
```

Or this( no exceptions will be printed as well):

```
try {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("55.11.55.131");
        factory.setUsername("e93b7d0d-ba17-42a2-91c6-d488863019fd");
        factory.setPassword("51681201-0313-4b5c-a0d5-006b345e25a9");
        factory.setVirtualHost("9d0cf636-17f5-4828-a21f-d7a4145f1f83");
        factory.setPort(5672);
        Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = conn.createChannel();
        try {
            channel.basicPublish("exchange_not_exists", "abc", new AMQP.BasicProperties(), "ABC".getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception2");
    }

    Thread.sleep(100000);
```

Isn't this exception caused by the `basicPublish` method? Why is the first type of code able to catch an exception in the second catch block?

Thank to @Mateusz Dryzek answer, I understand the reason for this phenomenon.

**But I don't understand why this exception is thrown not on publish but on close channel?**

Comment: It depends on the implementation. The [documentation](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-java-client/api/current/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#basicPublish(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties,byte%5B%5D)) says "Publishing to a non-existent exchange will result in a channel-level protocol exception, which **closes** the channel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using try-with resources which means that java will try to automatically close the resoures you created. If you take a look at the error message you can see, that the exception is thrown when java tries to close the channel:
// catch exception: Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #**method<channel.close>(** reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'exchange_not_exists' in vhost